# friend operator<< of a template class, with additional default template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

In the following code, `A` is a template class, depending on a non-type `bool type` parameter. A friend `operator<<` is defined for both `A<true>` and `A<false>`. The `operator<<` additionally depends on another bool template parameter.

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <bool type>
class A;

template <>
class A<true> {
    int m_x;
public:
    A(int x) : m_x{x} { }
    template <bool d, bool type>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a);
};

template <>
class A<false> {
    int m_y;
public:
    A(int y) : m_y{y} { }
    template <bool d, bool type>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a);
};

template <bool d, bool type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a)
{
    if constexpr (type) {
        os << "m_x = " << a.m_x << std::endl;
        if constexpr (d) { os << "2m_x = " << a.m_x << std::endl; }
    }
    else {
        os << "m_y = " << a.m_y << std::endl;
        if constexpr (d) { os << "2m_y = " << a.m_y << std::endl; }
    }
    return os;
}


int main()
{
    A<true> atrue{2};
    A<false> afalse{3};

    operator<< <true>(std::cout, atrue);
    operator<< <false>(std::cout, atrue);

    operator<< <true>(std::cout, afalse);
    operator<< <false>(std::cout, afalse);

    return 0;
}
```

See it [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d9d2a8518b61e37).

Now, I would like to give a default value of the template parameter `d` of `operator<<`, say `d=false` such that this statement

```
std::cout << atrue;
```

is equivalent to

```
operator<< <false>(std::cout, atrue);
```

because `bool d` takes a default value `d=false` and `bool type` is deduced from the second argument of `operator<<`.

Is there a syntax to allow for that?

If I insert the default parameter in the friend declaration

```
template <bool d = false, bool type>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a);
```

I get a compile error:

> main.cpp:14:71: error: default template arguments may not be used in
>   template friend declarations

If I insert the default parameter in the code of `operator<<`

```
template <bool d = false, bool type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a)
{
...
```

again it does not compile giving error

> main.cpp:27:15: error: redeclaration of friend 'template std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&)' may not
>   have default template arguments
>
> 27 | std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A& a)
>
> main.cpp:14:26: note: 'template std::ostream&
>   operator<<(std::ostream&, const A&)' previously declared here
>
> 14 |     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const
>   A& a);

Comment: How about use other name than `operator <<` as `print` as you cannot use it "normally"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, actually the solution was relatively easy. It is enough to add a *declaration* of the template `operator<<` before the class specializations:

```
template <bool type>
class A;

template <bool d = false, bool type>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A<type>& a);
....
```

In this way the `friend` declaration inside `A<type>` does not declare `operator<<` in first place, but only declares that it is a `friend`.
A working example can be checked [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f6de52c81091259).